# Set date parameters for recent activity

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

I was trying to find a comment I'd read (about how the website to use to post an image on SO), but found that recent activity is, well, recent.  How about we have a date range setting so we can look for all comments in a set period of time?

Answer (score 1):

I can do this for your activity and activity related to your posts. You should be able to go to the link below and modify the dates as desired, up to 60 days in the past. For anyone else, substitute your userid where I have to the OP's.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/13295?startdate=2009-07-01&enddate=2009-07-22&tab=responses#sort-top

Comment: I tried that, inserting an earlier date, and got no older information.

Comment: Did you look at the "responses" tab, that should show all comments within the range you entered.

Comment: The updated link would show all responses (comments) to your posts for the last month on meta.