# recent activity should have a "past N days" option

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

this is sort of related to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/set-date-parameters-for-recent-activity)...

If I want to look at recent activity, it works great... except for when I look at it early in the morning, and it doesn't show posts within the last 24 hours under the default "recent activity" post. So I look at the "this week" page, which works great... except on Sunday or Monday when it doesn't work well because it's a new week.

Is there any way to have it default to just the past N days (where N = 2 or 3 or 7 sounds like a good number)? "this week" and "last week" and "today" and "yesterday" don't seem to have much value. I really just would like to see activity that is "recent" and that depends far more on a fixed timeframe relative to the present, than a periodic timeframe that shuffles in and out of phase as time goes by.

Comment: +1 I hope something like this will be done. At least an option such as "PastDays=N" on the querystring, to go along side with the current StartDate&EndDate mechanism. It'd be easier to refresh and later could replace the StartDate on the "Today, Yesterday, etc" buttons, since it makes more sense - it'd be a "today" link no matter when you open it.

Comment: This would get my vote (if I had enough rep). I only care about the last couple of days or so when I click the envelope.

Answer (score 2):

While certainly understand that there is room to quibble over what has been chosen as the dates for each of the links provided (the "yesterday" gets me the most, since it shows yesterday and today); this is completely parameterized and you can enter whatever date range you would like within the last 60 days. I think what I would like to see most is a pair of date pickers, as there are on the reputation graph page. The hot links for certain ranges is nice, but clearly is confusing many users, and it would be nice to be able to select the date range, rather than edit the url parameters to get to a "custom" range.

Comment: we had date pickers and pulled them because people complained. They aren't coming back. Edit the URL if you need ranges

Comment: Agreed. I don't mind editing the URL if I want to hunt for something specific. I'd just like to see both (a) something really flexible (sounds like the URL params allow this) even if it's not super-convenient to use, and (b) something really convenient to use to look at "recent" past, where "recent" has a more useful definition than the "yesterday"/"today"/"this week"/"last week" that are provided.

Comment: @Jeff: so is there a way to get ranges by editing the URL?